# How to add scroller bar in Vaadin 7 table

Tags: java, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin I have a sub window. Inside the sub window, I added a table as shown in the picture.

I added the following property to the table:

```
    fileFormatTable = new Table(SalkkuTM.getI18N("VisibleColumnPanel.chosen.caption"));
    fileFormatTable.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);
    fileFormatTable.setWidth(240, Unit.PIXELS);
    fileFormatTable.setContainerDataSource(fileFormatListContainer);
    fileFormatTable.setVisibleColumns("caption");
    fileFormatTable.setColumnHeaderMode(Table.ColumnHeaderMode.HIDDEN);
    fileFormatTable.setSortEnabled(false);
    fileFormatTable.setSelectable(true);
    fileFormatTable.setMultiSelect(true);
    fileFormatTable.setDragMode(Table.TableDragMode.ROW);
    fileFormatTable.setSizeUndefined();
```

Note that I commeted out following since I set fileFormatTable.setSizeUndefined(); It has no effect.

```
//fileFormatTable.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);
//fileFormatTable.setWidth(240, Unit.PIXELS);
```

It added a vertical scrollbar. But it didn't add any horizontal scroller bar. How can I add a horizontal scrollbar to this table?

[image]

Comment: Did you try this  : https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/381092/628455

Comment: I'm just asking -> Is it normal to use the setSizeUndefined() and just before definied a width and height?

Comment: pls check updated question. Note that I commeted out following since I set fileFormatTable.setSizeUndefined(); It has no effect. 

    //fileFormatTable.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);
    //fileFormatTable.setWidth(240, Unit.PIXELS);

Comment: :) ok, perfect.
Did you see the link ? Try to add a panel in an HorizontalLayout  -> then, add you table as component in the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like, based on vaadin.com/forum/thread/381092/628455 :

```
Panel tablePanel = new Panel(); 
tablePanel.setHeight(400, Unit.PIXELS);
tablePanel.setWidth(240, Unit.PIXELS);

fileFormatTable = new Table(SalkkuTM.getI18N("VisibleColumnPanel.chosen.caption"));
fileFormatTable.setContainerDataSource(fileFormatListContainer);
fileFormatTable.setVisibleColumns("caption");
fileFormatTable.setColumnHeaderMode(Table.ColumnHeaderMode.HIDDEN);
fileFormatTable.setSortEnabled(false);
fileFormatTable.setSelectable(true);
fileFormatTable.setMultiSelect(true);
fileFormatTable.setDragMode(Table.TableDragMode.ROW);
fileFormatTable.setPageLength(fileFormatTable.size()); 

HorizontalLayout tableContainer = new HorizontalLayout();
tableContainer.addComponent(fileFormatTable);
tableContainer.setSizeUndefined();
tableContainer.setStyleName("innerDataTable");

tablePanel.setContent(tableContainer); 
tablePanel.setScrollable(true);
```

Comment: There is no method in Panel tablePanel.setScrollable(true); It seems like it could enable the scroller. There is public void setScrollLeft(int scrollLeft) and public void setScrollTop(int scrollTop). I added with 200. Then it seems I got both scrollers. Thanks